# Using git-flow - Where does my unit/integration tests go?

Tags: git, unit-testing, jenkins, git-flow

I am starting to learn about git-flow (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

I will put a webhook and start a jenkins job to make unit/integration test.
After that Jenkins will deploy the project in production.

Which branch can I make unit / integration test and the deploy? develop or master? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, deployments to production should only be done from the `master` branch. That’s what that branch is there for in `git flow`.

But since the `master` branch only gets a commit by the time a release is made, I would suggest you setup a Jenkins job on the `develop` branch to run all the test and get a more “continuous integration” feedback during the development process.